# What is happening after kill -CONT <PID>?

Tags: command-line, process, kill

I have suspend a process through `kill -TSTP <pid>`. Then tried to continue it with `kill -CONT <pid>`. But After completion of process, control is not returning to bash. Why this is happening? And what to do to overcome this problem?

I started the process (a shell script) from one bash (say bash-1) with `./name.sh`. Then suspended that process with the command `kill -TSTP <pid>` through bash-2. Finally tried to resume it with `kill -CONT <pid>` through bash-2. But after completion of shell script, control is not returning, it just staying there forever.

Comment: We need more information here. Are you starting the process from bash? Are you backgrounding the process or running straight in the foreground? Does the process indeed complete successfully? Some processes are sensitive to stopping (when timeouts and such are involved). Is the process still waiting on something? What's the `ps` output? Is the process gone? If not, what's its state? Is maybe just echo disabled? Try `stty echo` + enter.

Comment: Yes, started the process (a shell script) from one bash (say bash-1)  with "./name.sh".
Then suspended that process with the command "kill -TSTP <pid>" through bash-2.
Finally tried to resume it with "kill -CONT <pid>" through bash-2.
But after completion of shell script, control is not returning, it just staying there forever.

Answer (score 1):

Process started from a shell have a controlling TTY associated with them that they inherit from the shell and also belong to a process group. When running multiple processes in a pipe with `|` or using subshell notation with `()`'s, all those processes are started with the same process group. When the user hits the suspend keystroke, normally **Ctrl-Z** from the keyboard, the TTY layer sends the `SIGTSTP` signal to all processes in the current foreground process group and the parent shell wakes up with a `SIGCHLD` (or returns from it's call to `wait()`) to handle the TTY again. The shell is responsible for controlling which process group is in the foreground for it's controlling TTY and the shell itself resides in it's own process group.

If a process is not part of the current, foreground process group for the TTY, it will be stopped automatically by the TTY layer with a `SIGTTIN` if it tries to read from the terminal. For example, sending `SIGCONT` to an interactive text editor like vim will resume it, but it will immediately get a `SIGTTIN` as soon as it call's `read()` to get the next keypress from the keyboard. The shell must be notified with the `fg` job control directive that it should move vim to the foreground process group before resuming it thereby removing the shell from being in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

`kill -CONT` is something that is not understood by the shell.

For this reason, it just continues the process without any effect to the shell.

This results in something similar to a background process.

If you like to continue a process, better call `fg` or if this
is not the "current job", use `jobs` to list all current jobs and then call e.g. `fg %3` if the job in question is job #3.

Note that the difference between calling `kill -CONT` and `fg` from the launching shell is that with `fg`, the shell in addition to sending the `SIGCONT` signal sets the tty process group to the process group of the resumed process. The setting of the tty process group controls the automated delivery of the signals `TSTP`, `TTIN` and `TTOU`. Later the shell starts to wait for the command.

If you however called `kill -CONT` from a different shell/tty than the one where the process in question runs, then it should be really obvious that you just continue a foreign process. The shell that fired the `kill -CONT` will just return to it's prompt, but you see this.

Comment: Calling `kill -CONT` on a suspended process has the same effect as doing `bg`: it resumes without moving to foreground, except that `bg` sends the SIGCONT signal to the whole process group not just one process.